# C++ Create a class instance and pointer to it in one line

Tags: c++, pointers, syntax, instance, stack-allocation

There is a one line syntax to create an instance and pointer to it, in the heap allocation.
Is there one line syntax for the same purpose but with stack allocation?

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {};

int main()
{
    //Base* ptr = new Base(); // heap

    Base base;
    Base* ptr = &base; // stack  

    return 0;
}
```

I have no problem to use 2 lines, just thought maybe there is a special syntax for this case (I'm moving from Python :D)

Comment: Why do you need the `Base*` anyway?

Comment: It is possible to define more than one variable in a single declaration statement  e.g. `Base base, *ptr = &base;`.    It's not possible to eliminate the two parts entirely, since both variables (`base` and `ptr`) have names.    BTW - terms like "heap" and "stack" are not actually part of C++ (in this context) - heap and stack are specific concepts from some implementations (particular compilers and host systems) but not relevant to all implementations.

Comment: @NathanPierson This is just an example. But in the real case I think I would use it mostly to pass to a functions.

Comment: If you want to pass the address of a variable to a function, that variable must be declared before-hand.

Comment: You can just base `&base` to a function. You can write your function to take a reference and just pass `base` itself. That's why I asked about the actual use case, because it's not clear when you'd want this.

Comment: @Peter Thanks for detail explanation. So does it mean that the syntax from my example can't guarantee that it would be heap or stack and it will depend on compiler?

Comment: @Nick - I'm saying that heap and stack are meaningless in the context of C++, because they are implementation details that are not required by the C++ standard (and don't always occur in all implementations).   In C++, the terminology is concerned with life cycle of objects (e.g. a variable with automatic storage duration [lifetime bound to its containing scope or context], a dynamically allocated object [such as is managed using `new` and `delete`], and statically allocated objects).

Comment: @NathanPierson Got it, thanks. I have no real task yet, just learning syntax, and, to be honest, it's not too clear for me at the moment when it is better to use pointers or references. I just notice that pointer looks like has more functionality (iteration by +-1, ability to reassign address, delete variable from heap (if i'm not wrong) ) but in case of references looks like it can simplify a code.

Comment: @Peter Got it. Then I meant dynamic and automatic storage :)

Answer (score 1):

```
class Base {};

Base base, *ptr = &base;
```

But I wouldn't consider it "a well formatted code".

Comment: Thanks a lot, got it! Then I'll be using 2 lines.